# Search for a specific shape in the image

Tags: image-processing

I am learning digital image processing and I just met a question. If I have a library of several shapes (They are described by non-analytic functions), and I have a picture which contains one of the shape (the shape in the picture can be a scaled version of the original one in the library). Is there an efficient algorithm to detect this?

An example could be like this. Here is a real image

[image]

It contains a circle-like shape, which is described by a set of parametric differential equations f1(dx/dt, x, y, t, P, S) = 0 and f2(dy/dt, x, y, t, P, S) = 0, where x, y are the coordinates in two directions, t is the parameter, P and S are constants determining the shape. I would like to calculate P and S according to this image. Currently I am able to numerically solve the equation with a given set of P and S.

Thanks!

Comment: If you could provide an example of the image and the example shape you want to detect that would be awesome.  Also, there are several ways to do this: Template Matching, Hit or Miss with Morphology, feature detection via SIFT/SURF and matching keypoints and so on.  It's hard to tell what you want without seeing an example.

Comment: @rayryeng Example added.

Answer (score 1):

If the shapes are simple, try basic template matching http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html if you are expecting scale change, this template matching must be done in scale-space http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/pyramids/pyramids.html

Comment: Currently I don't have the images to match, since the shape is described by a set of differential equations. I can only numerically solve the equation and get the contour.